# Private REST API maturity levels, and extra layers of complexity

Tags: java, rest, api, spring-mvc, crud

This is my first REST based project, currently using Spring for development. As I started learning and implementing REST, I feel that I am starting to overengineer it a bit for a closed API that is basically a CRUD, mainly it will serve only a web application.

I don't feel that the concept of Resource is used at it's best here, and also HATEOAS(maturity level 3) feels a little bit awkward as the back-end and front-end departments work in the same office and I don't think that the project will scale, let's say, to Amazon levels where HATEOAS will shine, HAL also seems to complicate things and produce no benefits for us.

During this period, I understood how powerful REST is for a public API, but in our case, a private API, I fail to see the benefits.
With what mindset should I approach a private API design with REST Architecture in mind(if REST is even needed)?

Comment: HAL is just one format. The objective is to be able to discover/navigate the API through links. So it doesn't have to be in the HAL format, as long as you can fulfill the objective. I personally don't like the HAL format, but I do find having links to related objects very beneficial.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha, I agree with you, HAL is not a must and is often a matter of taste, but in case of HATEOAS is it necessary for a private API with a single and defined client(for now)? Are there any benefits other than depriving the front-end client of having to build links to access specific endpoints? As we can verbally communicate about which endpoint to access for specific actions.

Comment: If I am accessing a endpoint for customer, and a customer has a list of orders associated with it, do I need all the order data or would I just rather have a URL pointing to the order data that I can retrieve when I want it? Probably the latter. This is what I mean by discoverability and navigability. You should be able to navigate with different links. You don't see a benefit in this?

Comment: Links make the API self documenting, which makes it overall easier for the developer to use, internal or not. When exploring an API, I would rather see links to everything associated with the customer, than have to switch over to looking at some external docs.

Comment: Very good example, made things clearer. But let's assume that our API is only used internally where endpoints can be exposed through documentation and communication. And instead of having an endpoint for customer which in the payload also provides an endpoint for his orders, just have two endpoints api/customers and api/customers/{:id}/orders and pass them to the front-end developer via whichever channel you want.

Comment: There are different types of developers: those who like navigating through links and those who like docs. I personally like links. If I am cURLing the endpoint while exploring the API, I want to see links so I can see what else is related to the customer. You should have both docs and links. Satisfy both types of developers.

Comment: And I also want to advocate for HATEOAS, as it helped us facilitate the navigation through chapters of a course, as every chapter resource also provides links to the first, prev, next and last chapter.

Comment: You should apply REST principles whenever you don't want server changes to break clients. REST is just a generalization of the Web where browsers remain stable whenever a server changes i.e. URIs of certain resources or adds new content. When you don't need such properties (i.e. your server and client always changes together and there is only ever one version available) then just don't go for the REST-train, but don't fall into the marketing trap and simply don't call it REST API/client then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a **highly opinionated** question, so take everything that is written here with a grain of salt.

*In my opinion*, a maturity level of 3 does not make sense for an internal API. If you can control and update your API clients, the flexibility added by HATEOAS does not justify the added protocol complexity. As you pointed out, the main benefit of HATEOAS shines when you are not in control of your clients.

*In my opinion*, stopping at a maturity level of 2 is *good enough* for your scenario.

But then again, I do not fully understand your context and your evolvability requirements.

Comment: to provide more context: in the first place the closed API will be consumed by web app, and eventually by a mobile client. And currently, I am looking for best practices that will truly benefit a closed API.

Comment: From a REST API maturity perspective, considering you will deal with two clients, both of them internal, I think you should stick to proper usage of HTTP verbs and consistent URI design.

Comment: `maturity level 3` doesn't guarantee that the architecture follows REST principles actually, therefore IMO this divison is nonsense at best. I.e. one might utilize hypertext in order to learn the URIs of further resources to invoke but as the client preassumes that a resource has a certain type it will fail if the server changes anything in the respone. This is why Fielding claimed that [APIs should never have typed resources meaningful to a client](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html)

Comment: @RomanVottner well, if you want to shoot yourself in the foot (as you described in your example), I believe that no amount of design guidelines, principles and classifications are going to stop you. I think the whole idea behind the Richardson Maturity Model is to provide some guidelines, which in a given context, relative to certain axes of changes, could potentially provide some flexibility, for a given cost. It is not, by any means, a silver bullet of API design. You should analyze, before applying it, weather you have any of the problems that it is attempting to fix.

Comment: My suggestion to the OP was that he should analyze his specific context and decide, based on that, how much complexity he should add so he reaches his required level of flexibility. My feeling, based on my current understanding of his problem, is that he can do just fine with a CRUD over HTTP sort of API.

Comment: If you think about how the Web evolved to its current state you might agree that its success was probably provided due to its robustness and its freedom it gave to webservers providing web content. Besides HTML pages a ton of additional content is exchanged, like images, videos and what not. Plenty of features where added over the years through extensions or plugins. Instead of a browser expecting a certain link to return a PNG image, the client tells the sever what format it is capable of and the server will provide (ideally) a representation the client understands.

Comment: This is exactly what REST tries to provide to other application than the browser based Web. Most of the so called REST APIs out there are RPC just with a marketing label "REST" put on them. I don't think that aiming for REST is therefore a shot into ones own foot. I rather try to see the meaning into exposing the DB layer through an additional model layer and convert that to JSON through CRUD operations instead of directly exposing the DB itself, especially for an internal application. Plenty of stuff is already provided by DB, like views or user restrictions.

Comment: @RomanVottner I agree, the web needed a ton of flexibility and in that case it made sense to design it with that flexibility in mind. But I think few applications we develop today have (realistically speaking) the same constraints as the web. Don’t you agree?

Comment: Well, if you truly have no business logic (i.e. you actually do only CRUD over HTTP), RPC might be a more sensible approach.

Comment: From my experience at least, most application are neither 'the web' nor plain 'CRUD over HTTP'. They tend to be somewhere in between. I understand your point (and my engineering side actually agrees with you, it's way cooler to build REST APIs than it is to do masked RPC), but from a business perspective, architectural purity is rarely a concern. Our contexts are rarely purely technical.

Comment: At the end of the day, we are paid to deliver the best solution we can on time and in budget, and our engineering decisions should reflect that (IMO).

Comment: Voted as solution, as the insight I've found in those comments was so much more than I asked. Props to you @RomanVottner and @alexrolea!

Comment: @AdrianBrad glad our discussion was helpful to you in some way. To Alex, REST should be used in cases where an API might evolve over time and you aren't in control of the clients. I.e. I work in the area of EDI with a lot of different ERP systems. Our HTTP-RPC API is based on pragamatic principles and best practices from 5-8y ago and in the past plenty of ERP clients failed to interact with the API due to changes in the API itself or in some backin dependencies. The code is now bloated with custom logic and is partly hard to maintain. As noone would pay a redesign it lasts in the current state

Comment: ERP systems usually understand different formats. Some of them are standardized like `application/edifact` some others follow a custom specification or XML/CSV dialect. Currently the API dictates which formats (and which fields) a client receives when it would be more benefitial if the client would just send the media-types it knows how to process and the API would return those. Also, link relations and their accompanying URIs could be utilized to guide clients into up- or downloading documents and retrieve their state or geneate an archive of the past month.

Comment: The point I'm trying to make clear is, you can't forsee the future and even an internal API/tool might get public over the years. If you are in a situation where you have plenty of clients using your API (internal or external doesn't matter really) and you need to change something you have basically 3 options. If you already have a REST architecture you should be fine otherwise you either need to patch the changes somehow into your application or redesign it from scratch. Option 2 (patch), however, leads to either a hard to use API or hard to maintain code (or both) over the years

Comment: @RomanVottner Really good talk. You are right, if you don't design with flexibility in mind and end up needing that flexibility, you will get pain. On the other hand, if you add a lot of flexibility and you end up not needed it, you will have unnecessary complexity to deal with. Since none of us has a 100% accuracy crystal ball, no one can guarantee that you won't need extreme flexibility (or that you will need it, for that matter). In the end, you have to make a calculated guess (which time is going to prove right or wrong :) ) based on the (probably incomplete) information you have.